# Se dérouler vs se décliner

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, verbes, présentation

Les phrases ci-dessous sont toutes les deux adéquates et avec le même sens ?

> L'exposé se déroule en quatre étapes.
>
> L'exposé se décline en quatre étapes.

Quel verbe est plus approprié parlant du plan d'une présentation (exposé de parcours ou sommaire d'une présentation (outline)) ?

Comment: Je pense que les étapes se déroulent mais différentes versions se déclinent...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Se décliner* est plutôt utilisé pour dire que quelque chose a été développé en plusieurs versions ou variations différentes:

> Ce modèle de chaussures se décline en plusieurs couleurs.
>
> Cette voiture se décline en modèles sport, break, décapotable, etc.
>
> Nos cours se déclinent en classes pour enfants, classes pour adultes, classes pour seniors, cours particuliers, etc.

Donc, cela n'est pas le plus approprié pour parler des étapes d'un exposé - ou alors, cela sous-entend que les étapes seraient quatre versions ou variations différentes de l'exposé, pas vraiment quatre parties sucessives.

*Se déroule en quatre étapes* est plus approprié.

Answer (score 0):

Ngram [confirme](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=expos%C3%A9%20se%20d%C3%A9roule%2Cexpos%C3%A9%20se%20d%C3%A9cline&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cexpos%C3%A9%20se%20d%C3%A9roule%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cexpos%C3%A9%20se%20d%C3%A9roule%3B%2Cc0) que *Se déroule* (en quatre étapes) est le choix à faire.